Quarkus cxf 3.8 leads to Unsatisfied dependency for type io.opentelemetry.api.OpenTelemetry and qualifiers [@Default] error
We distribute an internal framework on top of quarkus and we wanted to know if our framework (tipically some extensions) was still compatible with the current LTS quarkus 3.8
In my test app, I downgraded all quarkus bom to 3.8.6 and I got this error at runtime about cxf:
ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type io.opentelemetry.api.OpenTelemetry and qualifiers [@Default]
        - injection target: io.quarkiverse.cxf.opentelemetry.OpenTelemetryCustomizer#openTelemetry
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[io.quarkiverse.cxf.CxfClientProducer$ClientFactoryCustomizer, io.quarkiverse.cxf.transport.CxfHandler$EndpointFactoryCustomizer, java.lang.Object, io.quarkiverse.cxf.opentelemetry.OpenTelemetryCustomizer], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=io.quarkiverse.cxf.opentelemetry.OpenTelemetryCustomizer]

I tried to downgrade my internal soap extension (based on quarkus-cxf) to see if it fixes the issue but no.
A part of my pom.xml:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-opentelemetry</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkiverse.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-cxf-rt-features-metrics</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkiverse.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-cxf-integration-tracing-opentelemetry</artifactId>
    </dependency>

I am stuck here without any clue on what can lead to this error.
Anyhelp will be much appreciated, thanks 
Edit 1:
In my debugging journey, I tried to comment this dependency in my pom.xml :
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkiverse.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-cxf-integration-tracing-opentelemetry</artifactId>
</dependency>

Then my app can build and run as excpected.
I cannot explain this behaviour, can someone help me to understand this and fix the issue?

Check if the OpenTelemetry extension or library is included in your Quarkus project.

Yes it is, I added a small part of my pom.xml in my post
